# Creating bounds of a certain size leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I want to create a rectangle around a center point, of x by y miles. So for example:

makeRectangle(pointer, 10, 5);

I ultimately want the bounds, so:

makeBounds(pointer, 10, 5) is fine

However, everything seems to be created in terms of creating edge points, which I'm not clear on how to do with lat longs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use twice the [`L.Circle` workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206206/leaflet-square-given-centre-and-square-width/35207211#35207211).

Creating 2 circles (one for your horizontal distance, one for the vertical) and reading their bounds, you retrieve longitudes and latitudes respectively.

The drawback is that `L.Circle` is not exact vertically (it does not account for geodesy), and once you move your longitudes vertically, the horizontal distance is no longer exact at those new latitudes.

But as a first approach and for small distances, this method might already be enough for your need.